# Getting Run-time error '4198': Command Failed on `PasteExcelTable`

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I wrote a VBA program to copy an Excel table and paste it into Word. It was working about a month ago.

Now I get an error on:

```
newdoc.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, Wordformatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

The error is:

> run-time error '4198' Command Failed

[image: run-time error '4198' Command Failed]

Simplified version of my code.

```vb
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
    ' Copies the range "A1:B2" from the active Excel worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")
    rng.Copy

    ' Opens a new Word document
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Set appWord = New Word.Application
    appWord.Visible = True
    appWord.Activate

    ' Pastes the copied range into the new Word document
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Set doc = appWord.Documents.Add
    doc.Activate

    appWord.Selection.PasteExcelTable LinkedtoExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True

End Sub
```

In place of the `PasteExcelTable` line I tried

```
appword.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

This gives me the same '4198' error.

My references were working last time, include the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library and have not changed.
[image: My VBA References]

My suspicion is that Microsoft changed the references or updated the library.

I tried this on a remote desktop and it did work. I need it to work on  my computer.

Answer (score -1):

I HAD THE SAME ISSUE AND USED appword.Selection.Paste. TO CORRECT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).